# Is it possible to have more than one task definition in AWS Multicontainer Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I need three task definitions in my multicontainer beanstalk environment (two scheduled tasks and one 'permanent'). Is there any way to implement this via Beanstalk?

Dockerrun.aws.json file does not seem to have the option to define more than one task.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible using AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition + AWS::Events::Rule defined in the .config file in the .ebextensions directory.
Note, though, that Beanstalk env properties (variables) are not automatically accessible from containers defined in TaskDefinition.

Comment: Could you share the resources you used it set this up? Or share the .config you created?